# Losing wifi connections after few minutes (qualcomm atheros qca9377 driver)

Tags: wifi

I'm new to linux, I have just installed it few days ago next to Win10. Everything seems perfect, but I'm always losing wifi connection after a few minutes. In windows it works good.

uname -r 
5.4.0-42-generic

lspci | grep 'Network'
07:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)

rfkill list
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no

Does anyone have any solution to this?
Thx

Comment: This is unmaintained, but should still work. Click [here](https://github.com/ajaybhatia/Qualcomm-Atheros-QCA9377-Wifi-Linux/) and follow the directions. If you need help following the directions then I can write up a more complete answer.

Comment: Thx for your help. I got this error:
"Generating local configuration database from kernel ...Kernel version parse failed!
Makefile:40: recipe for target 'defconfig-ath10k' failed
make: *** [defconfig-ath10k] Error 1
Generating local configuration database from kernel ...Kernel version parse failed!
Makefile:40: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make[1]: *** [modules] Error 1
Makefile:30: recipe for target 'default' failed
make: *** [default] Error 2

More complete answer would fine, thx :)

Comment: I am having trouble finding free time today and you're not forgotten. I had a couple of small errors and then it installed, asking for a reboot. Do you have `build-essential` installed and up to date? Sorry about the lack of time, but you're not forgotten!

Comment: No problem, its not an urgent problem, and thank you for helping me in your freetime. I checked build-essential:
sudo apt-get install build-essential 
[sudo] password for vik: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version (12.4ubuntu1)
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded

Comment: I know I said its not urgent, but a solution would be great :)

Comment: Sorry, things got hectic and I ended up closing the tab that was my reminder to return to this. I did some more looking and it compiles just fine in my eOS virtual machine. Along the way, I read that it could be a kernel headers issue and `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-firmware` may do the trick and this should be run after that: `sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf` that will disable power saving for wifi which may be what's causing yours to cut out.

Comment: Also, after the above, you'll need to reboot to see if it worked.

Comment: After the first command I got several message like this:
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8125a-3.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168fp-3.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_dmc_ver2_04.bin for module i915
I dont know if it is matter or not but the problem is still exists. (after the 2 commands)

Comment: Btw I found several articles and the conclusion is the wificard this laptop (legion-y530) is garbage, so I orderd an intel9560 card.

I really appreciate your effort to solve it, but its not worth the time you put into it. Thx

Comment: If you want, find a small USB wifi adapter. They're *really* cheap and many/most will work with Linux out of the box. I'm not sure of the specifics, but USB wireless adapters are very well supported. They are also capable of being tiny. You'll lose a port, but you'll gain the freedom to move around. If you *want to* then click [this link](https://www.newegg.com/p/pl?d=usb+wireless+adapter+linux) and browse. The dirt cheap, tiny Netis is one that I know for a fact works with my various Linux installs. I've had mine for a few years now, among others.

Comment: Thx, I'll check it